# Win 7/Python 2.7 32bit: OSError: cannot load library pangocairo-1.0: error 0x7e

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, dll, cairo

I want to test [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/) but it has a problem with the installation of `pangocairo`.

I successfully installed weasyprint:

```
pip install weasyprint
```

I installed gtk using [this tutorial](http://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), downloading it from [here](http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/index.php/Main/Downloads).

I also set up the path to gtk\bin.

```
$weasyprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "c:\root\python27\scripts\weasyprint.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 336, in <module>
    from .css import PARSER, preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 208, in <module>
    'libpangocairo-1.0.so', 'libpangocairo-1.0.dylib')
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 200, in dlopen
    return ffi.dlopen(names[0])  # pragma: no cover
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 139, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 769, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "c:\root\python27\lib\site-packages\cffi\api.py", line 758, in _load_backend_lib
    return backend.load_library(name, flags)
OSError: cannot load library pangocairo-1.0: error 0x7e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding this dependency. Hope this works for you as well.

```
sudo apt-get install -y libpangocairo-1.0-0
```

Answer (score 0):

For Macos (M1)

even after `brew install pango`  it shows the same error

```
pip uninstall weasyprint
pip install weasyprint
```

Hope it helps !